# Which value will be sent by <textarea> and why?

Tags: javascript, html, editor, textarea

```
<form>
<textarea name="test" value="no">
hi
</textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

hi or no,and reason?

I ask this question because I see javascript editors use `textarea.value = html;` to restore the content when submit,why they do this if value attribute is useless?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`hi` will be submitted. There is no `value` attribute for the `<textarea>` tag. See [W3School's textarea tag reference](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) for details.

To answer your question of why you see javascript libraries accessing the `value` property of a textarea DOM element, you have to appreciate that HTML and the DOM (Document Object Model) that javascript accesses are 2 different animals. In HTML the value of a `<textarea>` is its contents. In DOM, the value of a textarea node is contained in its `value` property. Although DOM property names often map 1:1 to HTML attribute names, they don't always and this is just one example.

Comment: Search `wysiwyg.textarea.value = html;` in this file:http://www.peej.co.uk/sandbox/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.js

Comment: @unknown (google): That's javascript, not HTML. Different context. In that context, a textarea DOM element does have a `value` property.

Comment: Try my example, Asaph - in Firefox 3.1 and IE 6 it alerts 'hi'.

Comment: @Salsa: Yes. That's what I would expect and is consistent with my answer.

Comment: But when I run alert(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea').value),it says "undefined"

Comment: @unknown (google): `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an array so you've got that a little wrong. Try this: `alert(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value);`.

Answer (score 3):

In a POST response, a `textarea` will respond with the contents of `innerHTML`. However, if you have set a value attribute to the `textarea` and you try getting `textarea.value` in JavaScript, you will receive the contents of the `value` attribute.

A browser should never display the `value` attribute of a `textarea` in the physical `textarea` because it isn't standard. The `textarea` tag operates differently from the `input` tags. I would assume it does that because the `input` tag doesn't support line breaks.

The value a user changes would be the `innerHTML` value (`html` in jQuery), not the `value` attribute like they do with `input` fields.

Answer (score 2):

A couple other points -

All browsers that support javascript return read/write values for textarea.value, 
consistent with the input elements. But you can't use **getAttribute**('value') or **setAttribute**('value') with a textarea.

You can also read a textarea's 'type' property,though type is not an attribute either.

If you set the value property, **textarea.value=string;**it is equivilent to 
**textarea.appendChild(document.createTextNode(string))**-

A textarea can not contain any other elements, only text nodes.

The text in the textarea set from value will be the literal characters from the string,
while setting the innerHTML property will escape any entities and minimize white-space.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a textarea is it's contents. The 'value' property does not have a standard meaning for this tag, so a form or JavaScript will get 'hi' from the textarea.  Here's a demonstration of this in JavaScript.

```
<form> 
 <textarea name="test" value="no" id='ff'>
  hi
 </textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<br>
<a onclick='showVal("ff")'>Show Value</a>
<script>
 function showVal(id){
   var snib=document.getElementById(id);
   alert(snib.value);
   }
</script>
```