# Form submitting in php

Tags: php, forms, textarea

--EDIT---
i have created a text box area where users can input some data,

Basically when i press the submit button, it should save the inputted data. here is the full code, i can't fix it. :/

The user entry does not get updated.

```
    <?php
if ( $act == "htmlprofile" ) {


 ?>


    <div class="contentcontainer">
  <div class="contentmboardheaderarea"><img src="images/header.png" />
<div style=”word-wrap: break-word”><div class="contentheadertext"><?php echo "$hlang2"; ?></div></div></div>
  <div class="contentheading">
      <form id="htmlform" name="htmlform" method="post" action="options.php?act=htmlsubmit">
    <div class="contentheading4">
    <?php echo "$olang15"; ?></div>
</div>
    <div class="contentmboardlistarea2"><textarea id="htmlprofile" name="htmlprofile" cols="33" rows="10"><?php echo $qry2[htmlprofile];?>
 </textarea></div></form>
  <div class="contentbuttonarea">
    <div class="contentbutton1" onClick="document.location.href = 'profile.php?act=index'";><?php echo "$glang3"; ?></div>
    <div class="contentbutton2" onClick="document.forms['htmlform'].submit();"><?php echo "$glang21"; ?></div>
    <div class="contentbutton3"></div>
    <div class="contentbutton4"></div>
    <div class="contentbutton5" onClick="document.location.href = 'help.php#htmlprofile'";><?php echo "$glang5"; ?></div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>


<?php
if ( $act == "htmlsubmit" ) {

$save ='Profile updated successfully';  
$query4 = "UPDATE members SET htmlprofile = '$htmlprofile' WHERE username = '$myuser'";
mysql_query($query4);
?>
```

Comment: I'm just wondering where your `submit` button is(?)

Comment: It's probably not submitting data because the POST action wants to go to options.php.

Comment: @Fred - I assume it's being called by `document.forms['htmlform'].submit()`

Comment: What is exactly inside `<div class="contentheadertext">` when the user get to the page ( I see `<?php echo "$hlang2"; ?>`)

Comment: @andrewsi I thought so too, but I didn't see any other JS to support it.

Comment: I noticed in your original question, an improperly closed PHP tag, which I suggested an **edit**. Here is what it looked like before `value="<?php echo "$qry2[htmlprofile]"; ? >">`. Might be the problem. Or was that just a formatting related?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `value` attribute  in `textarea` you have to enter the content between the `<textarea>text</textarea>`

See for reference [tag_textarea](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

```
It should be like this
 <textarea  id="htmlprofile" name="htmlprofile" cols="33" rows="16" >
 <?php echo $qry2[htmlprofile]; ?>
 </textarea>
```

Refer to this answer also [which-value-will-be-sent-by-textarea-and-why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885722/which-value-will-be-sent-by-textarea-and-why)

Answer (score 0):

Your div `contentheadertext` is not contained within the `<form></form>` so if you have inputs there, they won't be included in the form submission.

To resolve, move the opening `<form>` tag higher, so that it encloses all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

the submit works fine. But you have no variables with the post data definied. And textareas haven't "value". And when you don't need fixed strings in your echo, don't use the "

try the following:

```
<textarea id="htmlprofile" name="htmlprofile" cols="33" rows="16"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['htmlprofile']); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: I have already mentioned regarding `textarea` how your answer differs from mine ??

Comment: in profile.php there is a variable called "$content" how to submit to that

Comment: as i startet testing an typing my answere, there was no other answer. And I have mentioned some additional things.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to use a php variable inside HTML do that simply by echo $myvariable ; Quotes not required there. But if u are trying to echo a string use quotes just like echo 'mystring' .

Moreover when you are trying to pass some values as part of form submission, the required values should be between the   tags

if you want to show any value inside text area, remember it doesn't have a 'value' attribute. So write the code like this: value to be displayed